# Query is not filtering duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Query is not filtering the duplicate rows from two tables in grocery crud, i'm trying to show one list without duplicates and it seems query is being ignored by the controller. what am i doing wrong?

**Model**

```
public function delete_duplicaterow() { 
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT intervaloHorario, cita FROM intervaloshorarios JOIN citas '
                    . 'ON intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario '
                    . 'GROUP BY intervaloshorarios.intervaloHorario, citas.cita');
     return $query->result();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
$this->Fechacita_Model->delete_duplicaterow();
```

**Database**

[image: Database]

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you're grouping on intervaloshorarios.intervaloHorario and citas.cita.  You probably need to rethink your JOIN clause to join on both intervaloshorarios.intervaloHorario and citas.cita so that there is a 1:1 join with no row duplication.  Without seeing your table structure, I have to assume that you're generating duplicates because intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario and citas.idIntervaloHorario has a 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: Hi! yes, i'm in one to many relationship, i will update database structure. I have been trying your solution and it's still not working...

Comment: i'm unable to avoid adding duplicates, deleting or doing something like callback_before_insert, so i'm trying to make a filter without showing duplicate results

Comment: I have already post the database structure. Isn't that what you asking me for? :)